# How to convert IEnumerable type to List type?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am trying to fetch certain database values and store them in a datatable. After that I am applying linq to group by all the data with account number. I am storing the final result in a list which is of the following class type -

```
  class ListItems
    {
        public string accountNumbers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
         
        public string itemNumbers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

My code is :

```
List<ListItems> accounts = new List<ListItems>();

        public void GetItems(int ID1, int ID2)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_FetchItems";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", ID1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", ID2);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);

            accounts = from result in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                       group result by result.Field<string>("accountNumber");
           
        }
```

I am getting the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,
> System.Data.DataRow>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PricingPractice.ListItems>

on line

```
 accounts = from result in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                       group result by result.Field<string>("accountNumber");
```

I even tried to convert this expression using ToList() but it is also not working.

Comment: The issue isn't the IEnumerable => List it's that your generic classes are also not compatible. Without knowing what is in your datarow this can't be answered

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - one `ListItems` per many rows? If so, the properties should probably of a different type, arrays or `IEnumerable<string>` rather than just `string`.

Comment: If you want objects returned from ADO why don't you use an [ORM like Dapper?](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: I could not understand your question . Are you asking what values are being stored in my data table?

Comment: @RicardoPeres In my database my tables stores a account number corresponding to which I have many items. i am simply fetching them and storing in a datatable . I now want to group by those items with their respective account numbers and store the result in a list which is of my class type.

Comment: @Liam I am successfully able to store data in my datatable, its just that I am unable to use linq to group that data. If there is any other way to do that then do let me know

Comment: Yes there are plenty of other ways. You just need to map the records. The easiest way being using a `foreach`. Give it a try. Though like I said Dapper will just do this for you

Comment: Is it not possible with Linq????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ListItem
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
     
    public List<string> itemNumbers { get; set; }
}

accounts = (from result in dataTable.AsEnumerable() group result by result.Field<string>("accountNumber") into g select new ListItems { accountNumber = g.Key, itemNumbers = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("<itemNumber>")).ToList() }).ToList();
```

An explanation is in order:

1. I changed your `ListItems` class to `ListItem` and the `itemNumbers` property to be of type `List<string>`
2. I am grouping all items (, I don't know the name of the column in your database) to a single `ListItem` instance, grouped by the `accountNumber` column, and storing all items in the `itemNumbers` property

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change to list (.ToList()).

Comment: thanks it worked, but just trying to understand, what was I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, the DataTable's AsEnumerable() extension method returns DataRow instances, which you then must group, as you did. Then, for each element in the group, there will possibly be many items, so you need to select them all. Try to analyze the code and you will understand it better than I can explain! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will work hard to get my basics strong .